# Apply function to several variables with same name pattern

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` with many variables, I want to apply a function `-log10(*htotal_pattern*)` to some of the variables with the same name pattern `htotal_`. I.e. `Win_htotal_surf_eez`, `Sum_htotal_surf_LME` etc.

I know there is an `apply` function in R, but wondered if it could be done using patterns in variable names? As you can read in file names using patterns with `list.files`.

Comment: You can use `strsplit` to extract the `htotal` and then apply the function .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `grepl` to match the column names you want to operate on returning a logical vector, inside the `[` operator to subset the dataframe. Because `log10` is vectorised you can just do this....

```
df[ , grepl( "htotal_" , names( df ) ) ] <-  -log10( df[ , grepl( "htotal_" , names( df ) ) ] )
```

#### Vectorised example

```
#  Set up the data
df <- data.frame( matrix( sample( c(1,10,1000) , 16 , repl = TRUE ) , 4 , 4 ) )
names( df ) <- c("htotal_1" , "htotal_2" , "not1" , "not2" )
#  htotal_1 htotal_2 not1 not2
#1       10       10   10 1000
#2       10       10    1   10
#3     1000        1    1 1000
#4       10     1000   10 1000

df[ , grepl( "htotal_" , names( df ) ) ] <-  -log10( df[ , grepl( "htotal_" , names( df ) ) ] )

#  htotal_1 htotal_2 not1 not2
#1       -1       -1   10 1000
#2       -1       -1    1   10
#3       -3        0    1 1000
#4       -1       -3   10 1000
```